# Character Comparison to Input in C

Tags: c

I'm a C amateur, and am tasked to write a program that takes command line arguments, one of which must be either the character 'N' or the character 'A'. This is the method that I thought would work effectively:

```
//check argv[2], valid should be 1 at this point if argv[1] is an integer
printf("Valid is currently: %d, valid);
printf("The second argument is: %s, argv[2]);
if(argv[2] != "N" && argv[2] != "A") { valid = 0; }
printf("Valid is currently: %d, valid");
```

Given the input `./a.out 4 A`, and using `printf` statements before and after the given if statement, I achieve the following output:

```
Valid is currently: 1
The second argument is: A
Valid is currently: 0
```

I thought this would effectively make the valid-invalid bit invalid only if argv[2] wasn't "N" or "A", but it's not working. Then I tried to use `strcmp` in a similar code snippet, to unsuccessful results.

This is my first undertaking in C, so please be gentle, but I've tried everything from changing `"` to `'`, using `strcmp` instead of `!=`, and even using `atoi`, although I don't know if I used it properly. Is there something inherent in C string input or comparison I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare it as a string, try:

```
if (strcmp(argv[2], "N") != 0 && strcmp(argv[2], "A") != 0)
// can be reduced to:
if (strcmp(argv[2], "N") && strcmp(argv[2], "A"))
```

Or you can also compare it as a single character:

```
if (argv[2][0] != 'N' && argv[2][0] != 'A')
```

But that's probably not as versatile.

Comment: No... he has to use || .. it can't be N and A at the same time

Comment: @LewsTherin Indeed. Thanks for alerting me to my mistake.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña that worked, thank you. don't know how I didn't hit that solution using strcmp myself. I'll accept your answer as soon as 10 minutes elapse.